# Attachment as PDF is blank

Tags: apex, trigger, attachment, pdf

I'm trying to save an attachment as PDF inside a record.

The process happens after insert trigger - when I send the data to a function to generate a pdf as an attachment and saving it in the record.

When I send the data in English - Its work.

But when I'm trying to save the PDF in another lang (Chinese, Turkish, Hebrew, etc.) I'm getting back a blank content.

What I tried so far:

Trigger after insert that sends the saved record to the next function:

```
public class PDFGenerator {


    public static final String FORM_HTML_START = '<HTML><BODY>';
    public static final String FORM_HTML_END = '</BODY></HTML>';


    public static void generateSobjectPDF(Employee_Declarations__c emp)
    {




        String pdfContent = '' + FORM_HTML_START;
        try
        {
            pdfContent = '' + FORM_HTML_START;
            pdfContent = pdfContent + '<H2> 名  </H2>'; // nothing printing.


            pdfContent = pdfContent + FORM_HTML_END;
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            pdfContent = '' + FORM_HTML_START;
            pdfContent = pdfContent + '<P>THERE WAS AN ERROR GENERATING PDF: ' + e.getMessage() + '</P>';
            pdfContent = pdfContent + FORM_HTML_END;
        }
        attachPDF(emp,pdfContent);
    }

    private static void attachPDF(Employee_Declarations__c emp, String pdfContent){
        try
        {
            System.debug('emp -> ' + emp);
            Attachment attachmentPDF = new Attachment();
            attachmentPDF.parentId = emp.Id;

            attachmentPDF.Name = emp.Name + '.pdf';
            attachmentPDF.body = Blob.toPDF(pdfContent); //This creates the PDF content
            insert attachmentPDF;
            System.debug(attachmentPDF);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            emp.addError(e.getMessage());
        }

    } 
}
```

I tried to use the content-type :

```
    attachmentPDF.ContentType = 'application/pdf; charset=UTF-8';
```

but same result.
Any help?